# Grouping and counting results based on column PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table recording hits to pages like this :

```
id  |  ip_address       | page_id
---------------------------------------
1   |  192.123.456.78   | 2787321    
2   |  192.000.000.00   | 2787321
3   |  192.123.456.78   | 342415
4   |  192.123.456.78   | 2787321
5   |  192.432.999.80   | 2787321
```

I'm getting the results like this :

```
$getHits = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE page_id = $pageID" );
```

I want to display the results grouped by `ip_address` based on how many times each IP accessed the same `page_id`.

Example of desired output (where `$pageID = 2787321`) :

```
192.123.456.78 - 2 Views
192.000.000.00 - 1 View
192.432.999.80 - 1 View
```

I've been trying a few things (grouping mainly and running through while and foreach loops) but it quickly got really complicated and I can't get it to work.

Could somebody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Hint: MySQL's GROUP BY and COUNT

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I did try both of those but maybe I just set it up incorrectly? Could you show me an example please? This is what I tried... `$getHits = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE page_id = $pageID GROUP BY ip_address (hits AS COUNT(page_id)) ORDER BY hits DESC" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use  var for dinamic query  you are at risk of sqlinjection 
anyway

```
 $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ip_address, count(*) hits  
          FROM $table WHERE page_id = $pageID 
          GROUP BY ip_address 
          ORDER BY hits DESC" );
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. And I'm not using a var that's exposed like this - this entire script runs as a background operation, I just used it here for clarity.